# accessing the elements of a char*

Tags: c

I have a `char *p = "abcd"`, how can I access the elements `'a','b','c','d'` using only C(not C++)? Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use indexing:

```
 char a = p[0];
 char b = p[1];
 /* and so on */
```

Equivalently you can use pointer arithmetic, but I find it less readable:

```
char a = *p;
char b = *(p+1);
```

If you really want to surprise someone you can also write this:

```
 char a = 0[p];
 char b = 1[p];
 /* and so on */
```

Comment: I'd rather not advertise the third alternative to beginners without explicitly mentioning that it's a bad practice.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using pointer arithmetic for this case either, but there's value in knowing that the three methods exist

Comment: @karoly I'm saying that using anything but direct indexing (the first option) is insanity.

Answer (score 4):

Here, `p` refers an array of character pointer. You ca use the array indexing to access each variable in that array. The most widely used notation for this is `p[n]`, where `n` is the `n+1`th character [element].

example:

for the `1`st character, use `p[0]`, `2`nd character, use `p[1]` and so on..

Answer (score 4):

another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p="abcd";
    for (; *p; p++)
        printf("%c\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

result is:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [array subscript operator `[]`](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node97.html). It allows you to access the nth element of a pointer type in the form of `p[n]`.

You can also increment the pointer by using the increment operator `++`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p="abcd";
    printf("%c\n", p[0]);
    printf("%c\n", p[1]);
    printf("%c\n", p[2]);
    printf("%c\n", p[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

returns

```
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char* str="Hello, World!";
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```

2nd Method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char* str="Hello";
    int n=strlen(str);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c"str[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
```